# How to remove the last executed command html + javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have two pages, Page 1 and Page 2. For Page 2, my code is like this:

```
 $("input[value]").each(function(r) {
          if (r == 6) {
            $(this).focus();

            document.execCommand("insertText", false, request.data.email);
            setTimeout(() => {
              document.execCommand("delete", false, null);
              console.log('deleted')
            }, 3000);
          }
        });
```

I have successfully copied text to the input, but if I move to page 1, and then back to Page 2 again, and then I call the function, I'm still seeing the original data I copied before still there.

My question: How I can remove the last command of `document.execCommand("insertText", false, request.data.email);`? I have tried command something like this: `document.execCommand("delete", false, null);`, but it's not working.

Comment: There is the `undo` command, but your issue sounds more like you should be able to execute this function only once. How is set up the navigation between the two pages, how come your code executes twice?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, in this case i just want to handle if user repeatedly click button  and run copy function, i want clear last command of `document.execCommand` so not paste data `repeatedly`

Comment: Still doesn't make too much sense. If you have the logic to know that you are doing this action again, why don't you just stop the action instead of undoing the previous one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `undo` [command](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands), `delete` will delete the current selection, not the last command:

```js
$("input[value]").each(function(r) {
  if (r == 6) {
    $(this).focus();
    document.execCommand("insertText", false, request.data.email);
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.execCommand("undo", false, null);
      console.log('undone')
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your aswer, actually i haved try your solution before ask to here, now i know my problem come from my component render more than 1 time,